# structs within structs, dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, struct, malloc

I am making a 3D application where a boat has to drive through buoy tracks. I also need to store the tracks in groups or "layouts". The buoys class is basically a list of "buoy layouts" inside of which is a list of "buoy tracks", inside of which is a list of buoys.

I checked the local variable watcher and all memory allocations in the constructor appear to work. Later when the calculateCoordinates function is called it enters a for loop. On the first iteration of the for loop the functions pointer is used and works fine, but then on this line

```
ctMain[j+1][1] = 0;
```

the function pointers are set to NULL. I am guessing it has something to with the structs not being allocated or addressed correctly. I am not sure what to do from here. Maybe I am not understanding how malloc is working.

**Update**
I replaced the M3DVector3d main_track with double ** main_track, thinking maybe malloc is not handling the typedefs correctly. But I am getting the same error when trying to access the main_track variable later in calculateCoordinates.

**Update**
It ended up being memory corruption caused by accessing a pointer wrong in the line

```
rotatePointD(&(cTrack->main_track[j]), rotation);
```

It only led to an error later when I tried to access it.

```
// Buoys.h
////////////////////////////////////////////

struct buoy_layout_t;
struct buoy_track_t;
typedef double M3DVector3d[3];

class Buoys {
    public:
        Buoys();
        struct buoy_layout_t ** buoyLayouts;
        int nTrackLayouts;
        int currentLayoutID;
        void calculateCoordinates();
};

struct buoy_track_t {
    int nMain, nYellow, nDistract;
    M3DVector3d * main_track,
              yellow_buoys,
              distraction_buoys; 
    double (*f)(double x);
    double (*fp)(double x);
    double thickness;
    M3DVector3d start, end;
};

struct buoy_layout_t {
    int nTracks;
    buoy_track_t ** tracks;
};


// Buoys.cpp
/////////////////////////////

// polynomial and its derivative, for shape of track
double buoyfun1(double x) {return (1.0/292.0)*x*(x-12.0)*(x-24.0);}
double buoyfun1d(double x) {return (1.0/292.0)*((3.0*pow(x,2))-(72.0*x)+288.0);}
// ... rest of buoy shape functions go here ...

Buoys::Buoys() {
    struct buoy_layout_t * cLayout;
    struct buoy_track_t * cTrack;
    nTrackLayouts = 1;
    buoyLayouts = (buoy_layout_t **) malloc(nTrackLayouts*sizeof(*buoyLayouts));
    for (int i = 0; i < nTrackLayouts; i++) {
        buoyLayouts[i] = (buoy_layout_t *) malloc(sizeof(*(buoyLayouts[0])));
    }
    currentLayoutID = 0;    

    // ** Layout 1 **
    cLayout = buoyLayouts[0];
    cLayout->nTracks = 1;
    cLayout->tracks = (buoy_track_t **) malloc(sizeof(*(cLayout->tracks)));
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        cLayout->tracks[i] = (buoy_track_t *) malloc (sizeof(*(cLayout->tracks)));
    }
    cTrack = cLayout->tracks[0];
    cTrack->main_track = (M3DVector3d *) malloc(30*sizeof(*(cTrack->main_track)));
    cTrack->nMain = 30;  
    cTrack->f = buoyfun1;
    cTrack->fp = buoyfun1d;
    cTrack->thickness = 5.5; 
    cTrack->start[0] = 0; cTrack->start[1] = 0; cTrack->start[2] = 0;
    cTrack->end[0] = 30; cTrack->end[1] = 0; cTrack->end[2] = -19;

    // ... initialize rest of layouts here ...
    // ** Layout 2 **
    // ** Layout 3 **
    // ...
    // ** Layout N **

    calculateCoordinates(); 
}

void Buoys::calculateCoordinates()
{
    int i, j;
    buoy_layout_t * cLayout = buoyLayouts[0];
    for (i = 0; i < (cLayout->nTracks); i++) {
        buoy_track_t * cTrack = cLayout->tracks[i];
        M3DVector3d * ctMain = cTrack->main_track;
        double thickness = cTrack->thickness;
        double rotation = getAngleD(cTrack->start[0], cTrack->start[2], 
                             cTrack->end[0], cTrack->end[2]);
        double full_disp = sqrt(pow((cTrack->end[0] - cTrack->start[0]), 2)
                         + pow((cTrack->end[2] - cTrack->start[2]), 2));

        // nBuoys is nBuoys per side. So one side has nBuoys/2 buoys.
        for (j=0; j < cTrack->nMain; j+=2) {
            double id = j*((full_disp)/(cTrack->nMain));
            double y = (*(cTrack->f))(id);
            double yp = (*(cTrack->fp))(id);
            double normal, normal_a;
            if (yp!=0) {
                normal = -1.0/yp;
            }
            else {
                normal = 999999999;
            }

            if (normal > 0) {
                normal_a = atan(normal);
            }
            else {
                normal_a = atan(normal) + PI;
            }

            ctMain[j][0] = id + ((thickness/2.0)*cos(normal_a));
            ctMain[j][1] = 0;
            ctMain[j][2] = y + ((thickness/2.0)*sin(normal_a));
            ctMain[j+1][0] = id + ((thickness/2.0)*cos(normal_a+PI));
            ctMain[j+1][1] = 0; // function pointers get set to null here
            ctMain[j+1][2] = y + ((thickness/2.0)*sin(normal_a+PI));
        }
        for (j=0; j < cTrack->nMain; j++) {
            rotatePointD(&(cTrack->main_track[j]), rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: buoyLayouts is type buoy_layout_t** correct?

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using the STL like Lists and such out of curiosity?

Comment: why don't you use new allocator instead of malloc? new keyword calls a constructor of the class automatically. Thus, if you make a ctor try to alloc some memory needed.

Comment: yes i realize it could be buoy_layout * but I have been trying a lot of things to try to get this to work and that was one of them :)

Comment: Can you link the compilable code onto a gist, so we may run it on our machines?

Comment: Yes i can post an executable. Give me one second.

Comment: tigger did you want the sources that are executable, like a vc++ project or a .exe

Comment: no exe please, just a minimal source that I can build with g++ if possible.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mkaisercross/5333738

Comment: actually ignore the math3d.cpp and math3d.h files and delete the #include from Buoy.cpp. they are not used i forgot. just the main.cpp Buoys.h and Buoys.cpp should work.

Comment: here's a new gist https://gist.github.com/mkaisercross/5334063

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there are requirements for learning pointers or you cannot use STL, given you are using C++ I'd strongly recommend you use more STL, it is your friend. But anyways...

First, the type of ctMain is *M3DVector3D. So you can safely access ctMain[0], but you cannot access ctMain[1], maybe you meant for the type of ctMain to be **M3DVector3D, in which case the line for initialization you had written which is:

```
cTrack->main_track = (M3DVector3d *) malloc(30*sizeof(*(cTrack->main_track)));
```

would make sense.

### More Notes

Why are you allocating 30 of these here?

```
cTrack->main_track = (M3DVector3d *) malloc(30*sizeof(*(cTrack->main_track)));
```

Given the type of main_track, you only need:

```
cTrack->main_track = (M3DVector3d *) malloc(sizeof(M3DVector3d));
```

In addition, for organizational purposes, when doing sizeof you may want to give the actual type to check the sizeof, as opposed to the variable (there should be no difference, just organizational), these two changes:

```
buoyLayouts = (buoy_layout_t **) malloc(nTrackLayouts*sizeof(buoy_layout_t*));
for (int i = 0; i < nTrackLayouts; i++) {
buoyLayouts[i] = (buoy_layout_t *) malloc(sizeof(buoy_layout_t));
}

cLayout->tracks = (buoy_track_t **) malloc(clayout->nTracks * sizeof(buoy_track_t*));
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
cLayout->tracks[i] = (buoy_track_t *) malloc(sizeof(buoy_track_t));
}
```

Comment: main_track holds the actually coordinates of the buoys. Basically a list of [x,y,z] vectors. 30 is for the number of buoys.

Comment: ya that syntax is better, I wasn't positive that I could do that so I didn't, but ya I'll change that.